# How to deal with initialization of big models for tests?

Tags: java, spring, testing

I've made a class to store test models that are reused by many tests, I've been told that this is not a good approach ( I dunno why though ) and that I should have my models initialized right in test methods but the initialization takes a lot of code lines and the code will be unreadable if I do this for every method.

Here is the example how it looks like now ( many static methods that return data to be reused by many tests):

```
   public static RestaurantCreationDTO getRestaurantCreationAdriano() {
    return new RestaurantCreationDTO("Adriano's pizza", "Глибочицкая, 33/37");
}

public static List<RestaurantCreationDTO> getCreationRestaurants() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getRestaurantCreationDominos(),
            getRestaurantCreationMamamia()));
}

// RestaurantResponseDTOs
public static RestaurantResponseDTO getRestaurantResponseDominos() {
    return new RestaurantResponseDTO(1, "Dominos Pizza",
            "Басейна, 17", 1);
}

public static RestaurantResponseDTO getRestaurantResponseMamamia() {
    return new RestaurantResponseDTO(2, "Mamamia",
            "проспект Победы, 9Б", 2);

}
```

This data is oraganized in classes by the models stored inside:

[image]

And used by Controller/Service unit tests.
Is this approach viable if not how can I initialize such a massive amount of data before every test? @BeforeEach can be really huge and initialize the data before every test, though most of it will not be used.

Here is how testing looks now ( just take the data from one of the model classes ):

Service test

```
 @Test
void shouldUpateRestaurant_whenUpdate() {
    Mockito.when(restaurantRepository.findById(2)).thenReturn((Optional.of(getRestaurantMamamia())));
    restaurantService.update(2, getRestaurantCreationAdriano());
    Mockito.verify(restaurantRepository, times(1)).save(any(Restaurant.class));
}
```

Controller test

```
  @Test
void shouldCreateRestaurant_whenPost() throws Exception {
    var restaurantCreationDominos = getRestaurantCreationDominos();

    mockMvc.perform(post("/restaurant/admin/")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(restaurantCreationDominos)));

    Mockito.verify(restaurantService, times(1))
            .create(restaurantCreationDominos);
}
```

Comment: *I've been told that this is not a good approach ( I dunno why though )* well maybe start by asking your colleague who said this about why that is.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't have colleagues yet and have to find all best practices myself. I would appreciate if you could tell me if my way of making test model data is ok, if no - what should be used instead.
I would appreciate it so much!

Comment: Then who told you this isn't a good idea. That person is the one to answer that question as it is in his/her mind.